# Controls not working with ResignFirstResponder() in release mode on iPhone 5

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar, xamarin

I have a couple of UITextFields and a UISearchBar in my app that all have a ResignFirstResponder() on it so the keyboard would go away if the user touch the done/search button on the keyboard.

Now on the iPhone 3/4 versions everything works just fine on release. But on the iPhone 5 some of the controls just don't respond when clicking on them on release. If I debug on the iPhone 5 everything works just fine but in release mode it won't work.

Anybody got any tips/solutions? Xamarin products are all from the latest version.

**-- Added code**

The following part of the code the iPhone 5 is going wrong.

searchProducts = UISearchBar

```
searchProducts.ShouldEndEditing += delegate {
   searchProducts.ResignFirstResponder();

   return false;
};
```

If I comment this part of the code everything is working just fine (only the search button on the keyboard won't work).

Comment: Can you post some code? Sounds like a device-only issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it to find the UITextField in UISearchBar and on that preform ResignFirstResponder.

```
searchProducts == UISearchBar

foreach (var item in searchProducts.Subviews)
{
   if(item is UITextField){
      var tf = item as UITextField;

      tf.ResignFirstResponder();
   }
}
```